# do I have to repeat the dua for traveling on a transit?

Tags: dua

let's say I'm using a bus, and to my destination I have a transit. Do I have to repeat the dua again on the second bus? or just once for a trip?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I do not know, but what is the wrong with repeating it twice, thrice, etc. How beautiful is the "dua"!, it also does not take so much time.